# How to locate the accurate postion in pl/sql promptly (ORA-06502: PL/SQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a select statement which needs to select dozens of column into self-defined variable in my pl/sql. Like as below:

```
  select col1,
         col2,
         ....
         col30
  into   var1,
         ...
         var30
  from   table
  where ....
```

While executing the SP I encounter the error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too
>   small

The error information only points out the first line number of select statement. Even if i can figure out that my defined variable is too small to hold the column, it still makes me hard to locate the error-defined variable precisely. This is not an efficient way for me to debug this sp.

Is there any better idea, please advise me.

Comment: How about splitting it up into smaller groups just for debugging? Once you see where the problem is, you can out them in one statement again.

Comment: If you're selecting simple columns, it can be helpful to define your variables as `var1 table.col1%TYPE` etc., rather than specifying `varchar2` lengths which you might get wrong. (This also avoids having to modify your code if the table definition changes). You may still have to manually define variables for some columns, e.g. if you have a function call or a concatenation, but there will be fewer to check if you see this error. Also double-check that the columns are in the same orders in the `select` and `into`, that sometimes isn't obvious with a lot of columns.

Answer (score 5):

Two options are typically used in pl/sql:

1.Define your variables in PL/SQL to match the table's definition, using %type.

```
define
  v_col1 my_table.col1%type;
  v_col2 my_table.col2%type;
begin
  select col1,col2
  into v_col1, v_col2
  from my_table
  -- some condition that pulls 1 row
  where rownum = 1;
end;
```

2.Define a row variable, using %rowtype

```
define
  v_my_table_row my_table%rowtype;
begin
  select *
  into v_my_table_row
  from my_table
  where rownum = 1;

end;
```